# Codeigniter not working after moving direcories

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just starting trying to learn CodeIgniter. From the user guide it suggests to move the application and system folder for security reasons.

I now have this structure:

```
./public/index.php
./app/
./sys/
```

i've edited the index.php, adjusting the `$system_folder` with my complete path ending without slash and `$application_folder` with the compleate path without the final slash.

I' ve also edited the database.php file inside application/config/ to let it connect to the database. Those data are right.

Now, when i try to access `/public/index.php` i get a blank page

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer - I also needed to update the `$config['base_url']` variable.